# Where can I find CartThrob modules

Tags: cartthrob

I have a project that I'm working on in which I needed the Gift Certificate module... which can no longer be purchased. I already sold the project and this puts me in a terrible situation since Cartthrob closed it's doors so abruptly I have to ask if anyone has the latest working copy of the module (or any others since it appears these make be gone forever)

I hate even asking this, but there's no other option at the moment.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. Have you tried asking on ExpressionEngine Slack? You might get a bit more of a response there. https://ellislab.com/community

Comment: Carthrob and some addons have been bought out though the Gift Cert module has been removed from the Carthrob site. I suggest sending them an email...

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, CartThrob was recently taken over by us (Vector Media Group). More information can be found here: https://www.vectormediagroup.com/blog/view/vector-acquired-cartthrob-ct-admin/.

We've now put this back on the site, and added CartThrob Fees, CartThrob Subscriptions, CartThrob Wish List, and CartThrob Invoice. You should be able to get it here: http://www.cartthrob.com/.